# Loading a 2D array from an input file into a Function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble loading a 10x10 array from an input file and storing it into an array. I have written this so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void LoadImage(const string imagefile, int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS]) //Function to load in image
{
    ifstream inputs;
    int i,j;

    inputs.open(imagefile.c_str());
        
    getline(inputs, imagefile[i][j]);
    inputs.ignore(10000,'\n');
    
    if (inputs.is_open())
    {
        for( i=0; i < MAXROWS; i++ )
        {
            for ( j=0; i < MAXCOLS; j++ )
            {
                inputs >> image[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    inputs.close();
}
```

The void LoadImage function and was given to me with those specific parameters to use or the main function will not execute.
An example of an input file:

```
#Sample Image--1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Where I have to get rid of the header of the input file before building the array.
If I compile what I have now I get the "error: invalid types ‘const char[int]’ for array subscript
getline(inputs, imagefile[i][j]);"

I understand why I am getting the error, but I do not know how to fix it.
I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: The function `LoadImage` was given to you taking a literal multi-dimensional sized array as input? In C++? I suggest you find a better teacher, maybe someone who actually knows C++.

Comment: What do you think this line does `getline(inputs, imagefile[i][j]);`? The code would be better if you removed it.

Comment: Hey John, I have tried it without it. It compiles but it does not execute. My terminal just freezes.

Comment: Andreas, the #Sample Image--1 is apart of the input file

Comment: Side note: `if (inputs.is_open())` after `getline(inputs, imagefile[i][j]);` is a bit funky. If `getline` succeeded, the file is most definitely open. If it didn't succeed, you probably should have stopped and figured out why before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is generally OK, just following the comments and fixing a few small mistakes should work.
Note specially the terminating condition for the following loop:

```
for ( j=0; i < MAXCOLS; j++ )
```

Should be instead:

```
for ( j=0; j < MAXCOLS; j++ )
```

This is the reason why you're getting an infinite loop.

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define MAXROWS 10
#define MAXCOLS 10

using namespace std;

void LoadImage(const string imagefile, int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS]) //Function to load in image

{
    ifstream inputs;
    int i,j;

    inputs.open(imagefile.c_str());

    if (inputs.is_open())
    {
        for( i=0; i < MAXROWS; i++)
        {
            for (  j=0; j < MAXCOLS; j ++)
            {
                std::string str;

                inputs >> image[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    inputs.close();
}

void PrintImage(int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS])
{
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < MAXROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < MAXCOLS; j ++)
        {
            cout << image[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS] = {0,};

    LoadImage ("img.mtx", image);

    PrintImage (image);
}
```

And testing:

```
$ cat img.mtx 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
getline(inputs, imagefile[i][j]);
```

does not make sense.

If you want to ignore the first line of the input file, then you should simply use `inputs.ignore`, as you are already doing afterwards. So you can simply delete the line which calls `getline`.

Another problem is that the line

```
for ( j=0; i < MAXCOLS; j++ )
```

should probably be

```
for ( j=0; j < MAXCOLS; j++ )
```

i.e. you wrote `i` instead of `j`.